# Ensuring form does not submit on enter but instead runs function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, submit

I *think* that I understand that "button" are supposedly the correct way to achieve the result I desire; somehow they are supposed to be different from submit buttons.  But I don't understand how to get the result I want.

I have the following:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com">
    <input type="text" id="box1">
    <button id="button1" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If a user clicks the button, the function runs correctly.  (The function ultimately pulls the value from box1) and does something with it).  However, if while the user has their cursor inside the textbox, they hit enter on their keyboard, the form submits and links to google.

How can I make it so that hitting enter in box1 does not change the page, and instead runs myFunction?

Comment: you want to have it in javascript or would be also ok with jQuery?

Comment: To make sure the button doesnt submit the page use <button type="button">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add proper event handlers and listen for the submit event instead

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="box1">
    <button id="button1">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        myFunction()

    }, false);
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v1osxmk3/)

Comment: Any idea why that code might work for me in FIDDLE but not work for me in my actual test environment?  In my test environment when I click the button or hit enter I am directed to google.  I'm really frustrated with this and would love any help.  Here is both a link to my FIDDLE and a link to an imgur snapshot of my code in notepad++.

Fiddle:  
http://jsfiddle.net/zb5gv2vn/ 
  
Imgur: 
http://imgur.com/8bOCsBB

Comment: Did you place the script **after** the elements in the DOM, as in my example ?

Comment: I did not, and now that I changed that it works.  Thank you so much.  Would you mind either linking me or giving me a brief explanation of why that is necessary.

Comment: All elements are evaluated as they are encountered in the DOM, including the script tags. When the script tag comes before the elements, the elements doesn't exist yet, so `getElementById` fails as there's no element *yet* in the DOM, it comes later. So, either you put the script tag after the elements, or you use a DOM ready handler, `window.onload` or something like that to wait for all the elements to be loaded before the script runs.